# Remove Duplicate values from array Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a form in which 1 drop down is there which stores the value of another drop down.but the issue is the drop down stores the duplicate values.What should I do so that the drop down wont display any redundant data.

The code is as folows :

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="/assignloc">

                         <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:4%;">
                         <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="h2color" >FE Name</label>

                           <select name="selectpicker" class="form-control">

                                <% for(var i=0;i<pic.length;i++){ %> 
                                <option value=<%=pic[i].name%>>
                                <%=pic[i].name%> </option>


                               <% } %>


                        </select>
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="h2color" style="margin-left:10px;">Broker ID</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Broker Id" name="brokerid">

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">Assign</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to do exactly what you say in the question title: remove duplicate values from array. All that HTML is irrelevant, isn't it? What's the exact array structure and what have you tried so far?

Comment: what's your data response from the server? Do you just want to hide any duplicate values from the front end? Ideally, duplications shouldn't be posted to the server. If you also want to avoid duplications from the server in the first place, post your endpoint. :)

Comment: A general purpose unique filter for javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837373/code-works-with-arrays-but-not-multidimensional-arrays/30838163#30838163

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below fiddle for similar example of removing duplicate array in nodejs 
     https://jsfiddle.net/shreya7/rgn3y04e/

```
  var array= ["8","2","7","2", "6"];
  var earray = [];
     for(var i in array){
        if(earray .indexOf(array[i]) === -1){
            earray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

  alert(earray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pic= ["1","2","1","1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", "6", "8", "9", "2"];
var uniquePic = [];
    for(var i in pic){
        if(uniquePic.indexOf(pic[i]) === -1){
            uniquePic.push(pic[i]);
        }
    }

console.log(uniquePic);
```

Below is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/5bf3L78L/

Comment: Nice, but if you don't want duplicate values, they shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: @TonyBarnes:  I agree with you, but at some cases its acceptable... may be at different place they need with duplicates and at one place they don't need...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove duplicate elements

```
var unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bf3L78L/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using EMBER JS I have corrected code snippet for you

```
<% 
var pictList = [];
for(var i=0;i<pic.length;i++){ 
    var pictItem = pic[i].name;
    var unique = true;
    for(var j=0; j<pictList.length; j++){
        if(pictList[j] == pictItem){
            unique = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    if(unique == true){
        pictList.push(pictItem);
%> 
    <option value=<%=pic[i].name%>>
        <%=pic[i].name%> </option>


    <%} } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Set:

```
var array = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4];  //your array
var uniqueSet = new Set(array);  //unique set with no duplicates  
var arrayWitoutDuplicates = Array.from(set);  //re-convert set to array
```

Or in short:

```
var array = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4];
var arrayWitoutDuplicates = Array.from(new Set(array));
```